# PHP DOM: get attribute with DOM

Tags: php, dom

I am using `PHPDocument` and `DOMXPath`. I am trying to get the attribute with json type value. But I don't get the exact value. I could get the other attributes well but not this. The HTML looks like

```
<a href="URL" title="{tt4438848=Nicholas Stoller (dir.), Seth Rogen, Rose Byrne, tt2567026=James Bobin (dir.), Mia Wasikowska, Johnny Depp, tt3498820=Anthony Russo (dir.), Chris Evans, Robert Downey Jr., tt2948356=Byron Howard (dir.), Ginnifer Goodwin, Jason Bateman, tt3385516=Bryan Singer (dir.), James McAvoy, Michael Fassbender, tt1985949=Clay Kaytis (dir.), Jason Sudeikis, Josh Gad, tt3068194=Whit Stillman (dir.), Kate Beckinsale, Chloë Sevigny, tt3799694=Shane Black (dir.), Russell Crowe, Ryan Gosling, tt3040964=Jon Favreau (dir.), Neel Sethi, Bill Murray, tt2241351=Jodie Foster (dir.), George Clooney, Julia Roberts}">X-Men: Apocalypse</a>
```

If I use `echo $dom->getAttribute("href");` the output is `URL`
If I use `echo $dom->getAttribute("title");` the output is `Bryan Singer (dir.), James McAvoy, Michael Fassbender`

I cannot get the exact attribute value.

**Edit**
link [phpfiddle.org/main/code/dvj5-zf0q](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dvj5-zf0q)

Can anyone help?? I am new to PHPDOM. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an answer but the value of that attribute isn't JSON.

Comment: @alex So there is no way to get it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the title attribute:

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOF
<html>
<a href="URL" title="{tt4438848=Nicholas Stoller (dir.), Seth Rogen, Rose Byrne, tt2567026=James Bobin (dir.), Mia Wasikowska, Johnny Depp, tt3498820=Anthony Russo (dir.), Chris Evans, Robert Downey Jr., tt2948356=Byron Howard (dir.), Ginnifer Goodwin, Jason Bateman, tt3385516=Bryan Singer (dir.), James McAvoy, Michael Fassbender, tt1985949=Clay Kaytis (dir.), Jason Sudeikis, Josh Gad, tt3068194=Whit Stillman (dir.), Kate Beckinsale, Chloë Sevigny, tt3799694=Shane Black (dir.), Russell Crowe, Ryan Gosling, tt3040964=Jon Favreau (dir.), Neel Sethi, Bill Murray, tt2241351=Jodie Foster (dir.), George Clooney, Julia Roberts}">X-Men: Apocalypse</a>
</html>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $title = $link->getAttribute('title');
    echo $title;
}
?>
```

Be aware though that the `title` does not hold a json string but some custom implementation.
See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/wvig93).

---

To actually **get** the information, you could use some [**regular expressions**](https://regex101.com/r/sH8wH4/1) like so:

```
\w+=((?:(?!(?:, tt)).)+)
```

Broken down to your problem this would be:

```
$regex = '~\w+=((?:(?!(?:, tt)).)+)~';
foreach ($links as $link) {
    preg_match_all($regex, $link->getAttribute('title'), $actors);
    print_r($actors);
}
```

See a demo for this one [**on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/1o4NGA) as well.

Comment: Did you echoed the `$title` ??

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But in my case its not working http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dvj5-zf0q

Comment: It work cool with you code. I tried it but output is array with no values.

Comment: @hemnathmouli: Try it without the online Emulator (but on your harddisk).

Comment: Oops So that was the error. I must have tried in local. Now I got the output. Thanks a lot. I have to +1 and Mark as correct answer. Thanks :)